# Python Geo-database recommendations

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geo

I'm in the research phase for a new project, and I'd appreciate some recommendations.

I am looking to implement a geolocated supplier database, preferably in Python, such that I can do a search for a location, and the nearest suppliers will be returned.

Would it be possible to implement something like this in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. You will have to make a use of the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) and more specifically of the [Location-Based Searches](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Performing_Location-Based_Searches).